# Best practice in deploying SQL Server 2008 failover cluster over VMware ESX

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, vmware-vsphere, failovercluster

I am now in the process of building SQL Server 2008 Enterprise failover cluster for use with 3rd party server monitoring application (which also do some OLAP analysis for trends).

Since this project will be using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise over Windows Server 2008 failover cluster, I wonder do I have to separate the DB engine instance and the OLAP component or just make it as single instance altogether ?

yes I'll use the Physical RDM capabilities so that i can use the built in EMC CX Snapview for data replication to my DR site because the two VMs will be deployed across two different locations

I am looking for any specific tweaking for the VMware: maybe enabling the MMU and using VMXNet 3 and Paravirtual for the boot device ?

or within SQL Server eg. large pagefile in RAM, etc...

Any other suggestion and idea in tweaking and performance tuning of this failover clustering on top of VMware ESX will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

AWT

Comment: You can't use a Paravirtual controller for the boot device.

Comment: oh ? but I'm using vSPhere 4.1 now and Windows Server 2008 as the guest OS in the VM ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the paravirtual controller can only be used for non-boot disks.

Answer (score 1):

Wmware has a [good guide](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/sql_server_virt_bp.pdf) for deploying MSSQL cluster on ESX. It includes many best practices for configuration.

Comment: now i decided to re-think and draw again from scratch as previously it was my idea at 1 AM, so it seems that Failover clustering on top of VMware HA is too complex to implement and slight downtime ~ 5 mins during the failback/server restart is acceptable for me, therefore I have now decided to go with SQL Server 2008 Mirroring HA (see the attached). http://i54.tinypic.com/m80aj9.jpg--> the latest diagram.